# Recursion counting leaves in binary trees

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, binary-tree

I don't understand, why i am so incapable of coming up with a simple recursive function to count the number of leaves on a binary tree. I am ashamed to say, I've just been blank and staring at the monitor trying to figure out why everything doesn't work. 
Why is it so difficult to realize, what works and what doesn't? Is this supposed to be intuitive or unintuitive?

```
def num_leaves(tree):
    if (tree.get_left() is None) and (tree.get_right is None()):
         return 1

    #something goes here..


    return #something here..
```

Can someone offer some advice why I may not finding this as simple as its suppose to be

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with recursion ? it makes the problem easier.

Comment: Thats what im trying to do, I only identified the base case but im unsure of what to do now

Comment: Ok, the idea is that if you are in a node you have to count that node, so create a variable and immediately assign 1 to it, next you have to add to it the number of childs to the left, and then the number of childs to the right. Finally return that sum. If there are no childs it should return 1, the node alone, if there are left childs then it should be 1+childs(left), if there are childs left and right then it should be 1+childs(left)+childs(right)

Comment: This is to count the number of leaves? (all nodes with exactly 0 children)

Comment: Oh sorry, I was not aware of what you were calling leaves, anyway the idea is easily adapted from that case, it's practically the same process, instead of just adding 1+childs you only add 1 if there are no childs, otherwise if it only has childs left you return the function on the left childs, and if it has both you return the result of the function on the left childs + the result of the function on the right childs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is one of the first few times you've dealt with recursion. I say this, because I felt the same way, my first few times.

You have the correct idea to start with: you've identified and (correctly) implemented your base case. So, let's write down some thoughts about the solution before we actually code it up:

**Basic Idea**:

- Identify all the leaves of a BTree
- If a node has no children, it is a leaf
- If a node does have children, it is not a leaf. Count the number of leaves on the left BTree and the number of nodes on the right BTree and add them up

Ok now that we have the basic idea, let's try some **pseudocode**:

```
function countLeaves(rootNode):
    if nootNode has no children:  # this is a leaf
        return 1
    if rootNode has a left child:  # non-leaf nodes may be missing a left or right child
        leftLeaves = countLeaves(left child of rootNode)
    else:
        leftLeaves = 0

    if rootNode has a right child:
        rightLeaves = countLeaves(right child of rootNode)
    else:
        rightLeaves = 0

    return leftLeaves + rightLeaves
```

Make sense? Ok, let's write some python code:

```
def countLeaves(root):
    if (root.get_left() is None) and (root.get_right() is None):  # we are a leaf
        return 1

    leftChild = root.get_left()
    if leftChild is not None:
        leftChildren = countLeaves(leftChild)
    else:
        leftChildren = 0

    rightChild = root.get_right()
    if rightChild is not None:
        rightChildren = countLeaves(rightChild)
    else:
        rightChildren = 0

    return leftChildren + rightChildren
```

Now that we have that idea coded up, let's clean it up a bit:

```
def countLeaves(root):
    if root.get_left() is None and root.get_right() is None: return 1
    return (0 if root.get_left() is None else countLeaves(root.get_left())) + (0 if root.get_right() is None else countLeaves(root.get_right()))
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, I will process this till I fully understand it